# Drag and Drop HTML5 Images with a little javascript

Tags: javascript, image, html

I'm trying to make it so that in html5 when the image is dragged it will be dropped in a box in the header and the data will also transfer to the box. I need a label to address the name of the picture and then the rest of the pictures to go "Hidden" unless they press my reset button but that should reset the whole page.

What would something like that look like? or at least point me to a website to where i can learn it. I am just on a deadline and am having some issues with getting something like that to work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For years, we've been using libraries like JQuery and Dojo to simplify complex UI elements like animations, rounded corners, and drag and drop. There's no doubt, eye-candy is important for making rich, immersive experiences on the web. But why should a library be required for common tasks that all developers are using?

Drag and drop (DnD) is a first class citizen in HTML5! The spec defines an event-based mechanism, JavaScript API, and additional markup for declaring that just about any type of element be draggable on a page. I don't think anyone can argue against native browser support for a particular feature. Native browser DnD means faster, more responsive web apps.

For more details see this [**Article**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/). It will be helpful to you.